# Ayuda con Update SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
Codigo varchar
Cantidad float
Cantidad2 float
Cantidad3 float
```

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server la cual me da el siguiente resultado

```
Codigo Cantidad Cantidad2 Cantidad3
00428     0         0       32
```

Ahora necesito sumar 1 a las columnas float pero que sean diferentes de 0, este es mi query pero aunque tengan un valor 0 si les suma el numero

```
update SIPGProyeccion set Cantidad=(Cantidad+1),Cantidad= 
                          (Cantidad2+1),Cantidad3=(Cantidad3+1)
where Codigo= '00428' 
and Cantidad<>0 
and Cantidad2 <>0 
and Cantidad3<>0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres sumar 1 solo a las columnas que no tengan 0, puedes hacerlo con el siguiente query:

```
update SIPGProyeccion set Cantidad=(Cantidad+iif(cantidad=0,0,1)),Cantidad2=(Cantidad2+iif(cantidad2=0,0,1)),Cantidad3=(Cantidad3+iif(cantidad3=0,0,1)) where Codigo= '00428'
```

Como verás, el uso de IIF nos permite sumar 0 o 1 de acuerdo al valor actual de la columna correspondiente.

En el where, se eliminó la condición que tenías para checar que todos los valores fueran 0, ya que esto provocaría que solo si las tres columnas eran 0, se les aumentara el 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
update SIPGProyeccion 
       set Cantidad  = Cantidad  + (case when Cantidad <> 0  then 1 else 0 end),
           Cantidad1 = Cantidad1 + (case when Cantidad1 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end),
           Cantidad2 = Cantidad2 + (case when Cantidad2 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end)
       where Codigo= '00428' 
             and (Cantidad<>0 or Cantidad2 <>0 or Cantidad3<>0)
```

Detalles:

- En primer lugar hay que modificar el `where`, debe ser válido para cualquier `Cantidad` que sea distinto de 0
- Lo siguiente es usar un `case` para determinar si sumaremos 1 o 0 según la condición de cada `Cantidad`.